# Get updated posts from certain API using loop and with statement in Python

Tags: python

I need to check if there are new published posts from someone (every an hour), and if yes, I want to get list of the new posts. To do that, I first need to know the number of new posts. Therefore, I need to use loop to request the URL to get an approximate range.

Now I have the following `GET` API:

```
https://xxx.xxx?uid=1&ps=10
```

where `uid` is the user id and `ps` is the number of posts I want to get.

It will return a JSON object with the following format:

```
{
  'plist': [
            {
              pid: 1002,
              created: 1594474444,
              ...
            },
            ...
           ],
  'counts': {
              'ps': 10, 
              'total': 14400
            }
}
```

`plist` is already sorted with post created date.

`created` is the unix timestamp of the date of that post.

`total` is the total number of posts from that user, and I won't know this number until I get this JSON object back.

Here's what I tried:

1. Get `n` posts using the API.
2. Compare the created time of last post in `plist` (since already sorted) with the time I last updated.
3. If there are extra posts needed to be updated, get `2*n` posts using the API, then go to step 2; otherwise done.

```
import json
import urllib.parse
import urllib.request

def get_new_posts(uid, number_of_posts, last_update):
    params = {'uid': uid, 'ps': number_of_posts}
    url = 'https://xxx.xxx?' + urllib.parse.urlencode(params)

    with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as response:
         body = json.loads(response.read())
         oldest = body['plist'][-1]['created']
         if oldest > last_update:
             # do something to reopen the url using new params
             # and go back again
         
         # using binary search strategy to get all new posts
         return binary_search_cut(body, last_update)
```

My problem is that I don't know how to use the while loop and `with` statement together. Or is there any better method?

Comment: Can you clarify what are you trying to achieve? And why do you need a while loop?

Comment: @drum I need to check if there are new published posts from someone, and if yes, I want to get list of the new posts. To do that, I first need to know the number of new posts. Therefore, I need to use loop to request the URL to get an approximate range.

Comment: I still don't quite understand your problem, but if you want to do this every hour, don't do it in code. Instead write your script so that it gets the data, compare it to what you already have, then do an upsert strategy (insert if new, update if existing). To run it every hour, use something like cron.